# jquery parent hide not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Take this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BS6Es/). If you click the blue square, a red square will appear with a purple child square (apologies if you're colour-blind):

```
    $('#holder').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.parent').show();
    });
```

This works fine. When you click the purple child square, the red parent square should get hidden:

```
    $('.child').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
        console.log($(this).parent().css('display'));
    });
```

This doesn't work, despite the console returning a css value of `display:none` for the parent element. I wonder if anyone could explain why the parent doesn't get hidden, and what alternatives there might be to hide it?

HTML

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#holder {
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: blue
}
.parent {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
    display:none;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red
}
.child {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:purple
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#holder').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.parent').show();
    });
    $('.child').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
        console.log($(this).parent().css('display'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you have is that just after you hide the element, the event propagates to `#holder`, which is a parent of the `.parent` element and thus the event handler you defined on `#holder` shows the element again.

Add `return false` at the end of your event handler to prevent propagation :

```
    $('.child').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.parent').hide();
        console.log($(this).parent().css('display'));
        return false;
    });
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/EKApB/)

Comment: Why would the event propagate to #holder if they're not on the same place?

Comment: @itay Because the .child element is inside #holder.

Comment: @Itay - because holder is an ancestor to both elements.

Comment: @dystroy when you say 'other event handler'could you be a bit more explicit?  I still don't get why this bubbles up the dom tree, and more specifically why that prevents the element from hiding.

Comment: It doesn't prevent the element from hiding. #holder is a parent of the .child element so the event handler you defined with `$('#holder').click(function(){` is triggered when the event bubbles and shows the .parent element immediately again.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BS6Es/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#holder').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.parent').show();
    });
    $('.child').click(function(e){
       $(this).parent().hide();
       return false;    // important!        
    });        
});
```

You've to return false. Have fun!

**Update**: as already mentioned, you can use `closest()`instead of `parent()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use stopPropagation, which will stop other events from occurring while you're clicking.

```
$(function(){
    $('#holder').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.parent').show();
    });
    $('.child').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });        
});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BS6Es/2/

Answer (score -2):

Use `$(this).closest('div.parent').hide()`

Comment: This doesn't stop the issue the OP has and the click will still bubble up the DOM to the parent and cause the parent div to be shown immediately.

Comment: @j08691 Yes i forgot to add .parent with it. it must be like  $(this).closest('div.parent').hide(); But why you voted down it.

Comment: That still won't solve the problem. You need to use `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()` as a few of the other answers have already pointed out.